# Start and end on (near) the route in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I am working on a searching system which should detect if start and end point is on (near 50 km) the route. I have many routes stored in mysql DB as points [300k rows].

```
Structure 
id [primary] | id_route | id_point | lat_lng_point (spatial index) 
1              1          1          [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
2              1          2          [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
3              1          3          [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
4              1          4          [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
5              2          1          [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
6              2          2          [GEOMETRY - 25 B]
...            ...        ...        ...
```

Question is how to most effectivelly select just routes (route_id) on which (or near 50 km) start and end points is?

I have tryed union [in example] (or inner join) which works, but the query takes around **0.4s** which is too much. **Any idea how to optimize?**

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT(id_route)
                FROM route_path2
                WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
                                    Point(($lng_start+(50/111)), ($lat_start+(50/111))),
                                    Point(($lng_start-(50/111)), ($lat_start-(50/111)))
                                 ), route_path2.lat_lng_point )
            )
        UNION ALL
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT(id_route)
                FROM route_path2
                WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
                                    Point(($lng_end+(50/111)), ($lat_end+(50/111))),
                                    Point(($lng_end-(50/111)), ($lat_end-(50/111)))
                                 ), route_path2.lat_lng_point )
            ) 

        ) AS t GROUP BY id_route HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

**EDIT:**

I made optimization based on @Djeramon advice ano now **0.06s** I dont know this is the best what I can achieve and what if I will have 50M rows:)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE starts_on_route AS
SELECT DISTINCT id_route
FROM route_path2
WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    Point((17.1077+(50/111)), (48.1486+(50/111))),
                    Point((17.1077-(50/111)), (48.1486-(50/111)))
                 ), route_path2.lat_lng_point );

CREATE INDEX starts_on_route_inx ON starts_on_route(id_route);

SELECT DISTINCT route_path2.id_route
FROM route_path2
LEFT JOIN starts_on_route 
ON route_path2.id_route = starts_on_route.id_route
WHERE ST_Contains( ST_MakeEnvelope(
    Point((18.7408+(50/111)), (49.2194+(50/111))),
    Point((18.7408-(50/111)), (49.2194-(50/111)))
), lat_lng_point )
AND route_path2.id_route = starts_on_route.id_route;
```

Comment: Have you tried with an exists subquery or just with a simple `and` condition? Union would be used for an or condition. Another solution could be to store the 50 km envelope in an indexed calculated field (if you can create spatial index on a calculated field) and run the query on that.

Comment: Hmm, I dont have idea how to realize your recommendations, to get same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're running the query twice on the entire route table. Try to run the first subquery to determine all routes with a valid start point and run the second subquery only on those relevant routes. This should safe you approximately 50% of processing time.

One approach would be using a temporary table to store the result of the first query. However, you need to watch out for the created overhead and it's probably a good idea to create an index for it. For a few more details refer to http://blog.endpoint.com/2015/02/temporary-tables-in-sql-query.html

Comment: thank you I followed your suggestion [added to question] and now 0.06s, so much better. Myabe this is the best. I am just worried if 50M rows :)